# Create model for JSON in Angular 9

Tags: json, angular

I want to model this api response; as you see for each id we should create a property and add to object model
API response is :

```
{
    "result": {
        "id_8knimfclf": {
            "text1": "X^2 is a function.",
            "type": "truefalse",
            "choices": ["true", "false"],
            "marks": 1,
            "answer": "false"
        },
        "id_8knimfcle": {
            "text1": "Which one is true?",
            "type": "multichoice",
            "choices": ["first", "second", "third"],
            "marks": 3,
            "answer": "first"
        },
    ....there are a lot of id due to user data enterance
    }
}
```

I create something like this:

```
export interface details{
   text1?string;
   type?:string;
   marks?:string;
   choices?:string[];
   answer?:string;

}
export class model{
id?:string;
detail?:details;
constructor(id:string,detail:details){
this.id=id;
this.details=detail;
}
}
```

but the output json file an array of object like below

```
    [
      {id:"id_8knimfclf",
      details:{"text1": "X^2 is a function.","type": "truefalse","marks": 1,"choices": ["true", "false"],"answer": "false"}},
    
     {id:"id_8knimfcle",
      details:{"text1": "Which one is true","type": "multichoice","marks": 1,"choices": ["first", "second", "third"],"answer": "false"}},

//other id 
    ]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: http://json2ts.com/

Comment: @Hadi can you provide what behavior do you expect?

Comment: @n_denny Actually , I have a list of objects. every object has an id and a details object as a property. so I would like to send this list to API , the API response was declared above , I do not want to send some thing like "id:id_8knimfclf" and " details:{an object}" I want to send "id_8knimfclf:{an object}" , Hope I explained well

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you convert an object to JSON the name of property becomes the key of the json.

If i take the example array of elements you provided and i run it in [json2ts](http://json2ts.com/) i have the following output models:

```
export interface Id8knimfclf {
  text1: string;
  type: string;
  choices: string[];
  marks: number;
  answer: string;
}

export interface Id8knimfcle {
  text1: string;
  type: string;
  choices: string[];
  marks: number;
  answer: string;
}

export interface Result {
  id_8knimfclf: Id8knimfclf;
  id_8knimfcle: Id8knimfcle;
}

export interface RootObject {
  result: Result;
}
```

But i imagine it's not very useful to create a interface/model of every possible "id" of your list, also because probably you don't know which values you will have.

So we can use a trick that come from javascript and a loose object in which we can assign the name of the property dynamically instead of the value

Let's create out loose object

```
export interface Result {
  [key: string]: details;
}
```

To use it to define the property name with the id values

```
private convertToJson(models: model[]): string {
  const results: Result[] = [];
  for (let model of models) {
    let result: Result = {};
    result[model.id] = model.details;
    results.push(result);
  }
  return JSON.stringify(results);
}
```

So if you provide this input to the convertToJson function

```
[
  {
    id: "id_8knimfclf",
    details: {
      text1: "X^2 is a function.",
      type: "truefalse",
      marks: 1,
      choices: ["true", "false"],
      answer: "false"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "id_8knimfcle",
    details: {
      text1: "Which one is true",
      type: "multichoice",
      marks: 1,
      choices: ["first", "second", "third"],
      answer: "false"
    }
  }
]
```

You will have the JSON you looking for as output:

`[{"id_8knimfclf":{"text1":"X^2 is a function.","type":"truefalse","marks":1,"choices":["true","false"],"answer":"false"}},{"id_8knimfcle":{"text1":"Which one is true","type":"multichoice","marks":1,"choices":["first","second","third"],"answer":"false"}}]`

I have create this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uu7mvj) that prints the result in console.